# How to add IAM policy for all existed users and new users in AWS IAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have one AWS account which contains all my stuff and would like to secure it.

I would like to create an IAM Policy with some deny actions and apply the policy to all existed and future users. How can I do that?

I tried to use IAM Groups but someone can create a user without a specific group. Besides, I tried Organization SCP but it seems it doesn't work with the master account.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to create an IAM Policy with some deny actions and apply the policy to all existed and future users.

In these cases - the SCP is a way to go. And follow a rule  that all user may be created only in a sub-account. For complex organizations it is even one of the approaches to create a separate account only for IAM management.

If you want to deny specific resources (s3, kms,..) you could  apply a resource policy to deny some actions and deny update the policy (except the root/dedicated user).

> Organization SCP but it seems it doesn't work with the master account

Indeed.

If you really want to enforce that all users are in a specific group (regardless a root account or not), you may  create an AWS Config rule to check for user membership and add a user to the group if the user is not compliant to the rule.

Or maybe having a CloudTrail log with a rule that when a user is created / updated, check and assign the group. Then you have to protect the AWS Config or CloudTrail setup